# How to get currentContext of a widget inside a listview after scrolling problematically?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a flutter app and want to get currentContext of a widget inside a listview. I know to get currentContext the widget must be rendered and it work just fine when I scroll the list manually, as soon as the widget is rendered I can get currentContext of that widget for its key.

The Problem arise when I use *jumeTo()* or *animateTo()* on the listview's controller. I can see the specific widget is being rendered but *currentContext()* still returns null.

Comment: what do you need item's `currentContext` for?

Comment: To get height of the item.

Comment: you set the height when you build it - inside `ListView.builder` for example

Comment: item's height depends on the their content. I cant set a fixed height.

Comment: aaa, ok, that makes difference

Comment: `ScrollController#animateTo` returns a `Future` - did you try to get the context when that `Future` completes?

Comment: Haven't tried that. will get back to u after trying that. Tnx for the help.

Comment: `controller.animateTo(1000).then(() { check context here });`

Comment: Thank you very much! it worked. I need this to know height of every item in a listview a head of time to analyze how much time a user spend on an item before scrolling down. I was thinking when user opens it for the first time the app will calculate ever items height and gather offsets then store them in db, that way the app will never have to calculate the height every time a user opens the app. Do u think any other efficient way of doing the same thing. Tnx again that was really helpful.

Comment: and why not to use ListView.builder and check the time when items are built?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: instead of ListView() use ListView.builder()

Comment: I am using `ListView.builder()`. I can get context of items that are rendered but I cannot get those that are not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollController#animateTo` returns a `Future`

Get the context when that `Future` completes

`controller.animateTo(1000).then(() { check context here });`

Answer By [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink)